# Stored procedures and Triggers in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

I never used these two features in PostgreSQL. Which language is used to write stored procedures and triggers in PGSQL? Is it the same that Oracle or SQL Server follows or it is C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Far more common for writing functions is [pl/pgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/plpgsql.html) but you can use C if you really want to.

Comment: Is there any option to use standard Oracle or SQL Server style?

Comment: Not that I know of. In addition to the core procedural languages there are some third party ones: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/external-projects.html

Comment: Way more appropriate link would be: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xplang.html

Answer (score 1):

It's called PL/PgSQL and is similar to others.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpgsql.html

You can *call* C code functions as well.

Answer (score 0):

if your are working with text data in stored procedures Perl will be very usefull. I myself use PL/PERL.